# Simplifying Stacked Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to simplify the following:

$$10^{24}(.1^{10^9})$$

I think this can be rewritten as:

$$10^{24}((10^{-1})^{10^9})$$

If memory serves (though algebra was 30 years ago) if we have stacked exponents (for example ${10^3}^{^5}$), I can simplify by multiplying the exponents (for example, ${10^3}^{^5}$ = $10^{15}$).

But this is $10^{-1}$, raised to $10^9$.  Am I on the right track here, rewriting as follows:

$$10^{24}((10^{-1})^{10^9})$$ 
$$10^{24}((10^{-1})^{1,000,000,000})$$
$$10^{24}(10^{-1,000,000,000})$$

and then after we multiply 24 times -1,000,000,000 we get

$$10^{-24,000,000,000}$$

Comment: The law you remember is correct if you group $10^{3^5}=\left( 10^3 \right)^5=10^{15}$.  The usual convention is that $10^{3^5}$ is read as $10^{(3^5)}$ for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last step is incorrect, when you have $10^x10^y$, you **add** the exponents, so you get

$$
10^{24 - 1,000,000,000} = 10^{-999,999,976}
$$

Comment: D'oh!  Yes you are completely right.  Thank you very much.